# Who is included in the word "our" in Isaiah 53:4?

Tags: word-study, isaiah, healing

Who is included in the word "our" in Isaiah 53:4? "Surely he hath borne our griefs, and carried our sorrows"

Obviously in verse 5 the word "our" is for every human being because in the new testament it says that Jesus bore the sin of the world.

Isaiah 53:5

> "But he was wounded for our transgressions, he was bruised for our iniquities: the chastisement of our peace was upon him; and with his stripes we are healed)"

But what about the word "our" in verse 4? Isaiah was speaking to the people of Israel, right? But are all humans included in that word?

Comment: Does "Our" not refer to the עַבְדֵ֨י יְהֹוָ֧ה "servants of YHVH", as stated in Isaiah 54:17?

Comment: Is not "our" all of humanity like the "many" in Rom 5?

Answer (score 2):

Isaiah 53:

> 4
> Surely he took up **our** pain and bore **our** suffering, yet we considered him punished by God, stricken by him, and afflicted.

But what about the word "our" in verse 4? Isaiah was speaking to the people of Israel, right?

Right, that's the narrow local context. Let's see the broader context, Isaiah 53:l

> 1 Who has believed **our** message
> and to whom has the arm of the Lord been revealed?

Here there is a hint that the message is from the local Israelites to the Gentiles.
Zoom out a bit more,
Isaiah 49:

> 1  Listen to me, you islands; **hear** this, you **distant nations**: Before I was born the LORD called me; from my mother’s womb he has spoken my name.

The message was for Jews and Gentiles.

But are all humans included in that word "our" in Isaiah 53:4?

Yes. This was how Peter understood it as well, 1 Peter 2:

> 24 “He himself bore **our** sins” in his body on the cross, so that we might die to sins and live for righteousness; “by his wounds **you** have been healed.”

i.e., Jews and Gentiles

> 25 For “**you** were like sheep going astray,” but now you have returned to the Shepherd and Overseer of your souls.

Does Isaiah 53:4 really apply to humans that disregard the existence of Elohim?

The message of Isaiah 53:4 is to be delivered to all people. After having heard the message, if they do not believe the message, then the content of the message does not necessarily take effect on the unbelieving hearers.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  John 1:9 also indicates that the Word came to be the light of every person (ἄνθρωπον) that comes into this world.

Comment: Please explain how "our" in Isaiah 53:4 applies to all humans - if some humans disregard the existence of God. | The humans referenced in Isaiah 53:4 state : "yet **we** accounted him as plagued, smitten by God and oppressed." (וַֽאֲנַ֣חְנוּ חֲשַׁבְנֻ֔הוּ נָג֛וּעַ מֻכֵּ֥ה אֱלֹהִ֖ים וּמְעֻנֶּֽה). - so Why would other humans (who disregard the existence of Elohim) claim Elohim punished His servant for **"our"** sins? - **Does Isaiah 53:4 really apply to humans that disregard the existence of Elohim?**

Comment: Good questions. I added to clarify. Thanks :)